# Downloading files using express server from another site result in full html source instead of the actuall file

Tags: node.js, express, download, axios

I am trying to download a file on the express server filesystem trough axios but the problem is that I get the site source html instead of the actual file. But if I visit the site the file downloads fine.

Here is the express route I'm using.

```
Router.route('/:file(*)').get(function (req, res) {
    var file = req.params.file;
    async function downloadImage () {  
        const url = 'https://www.hikingproject.com/trail/gpx/7022698'
        const path = Path.resolve(__dirname, '../images', 'code.gpx')
        const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(path)

        const response = await Axios({
          url,
          method: 'GET',
          responseType: 'stream'
        })

        response.data.pipe(writer)

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          writer.on('finish', resolve)
          writer.on('error', reject)
        })
      }

      downloadImage()  
  });
```

What I'm trying to do is get some geodata using the gpx files and transform it to a geojson data.

Comment: What exact data are you trying to get from that page?

Comment: It's a .gpx file. But when I visit that page it just downloads the file automatically without loading any other content.

Comment: The link you have in your question returns a 302 redirect.  I don't personally know if you have the wrong URL or if the service is detecting that something is missing from the request like a cookie or some sort of auth header or something like that and therefore won't let you have access to the GPX file.

Comment: If you turn off automatic redirection following and then look at the response status from Axios and at the `location` header in the response, you will see the 302 status and the location URL for the redirect.  I can't tell you why the service is doing the redirect.

Comment: Also, once you login and successfully do the download, it appears like the actual download URL is this: `https://www.hikingproject.com/trail/hike/98/70226982708cb5daec50152015a93b34138a52a/1586855711/wiesenttal-trail.gpx`.  I don't know if that URL is specific to my account or what, but that's what the page actually uses to do the download.  I think login cookies are required and you probably have to go through a successful redirect to get the actual download URL.